# Button Not working iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, button

I inserted a button in IB, added this code in the .h file

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

Connected the action to the button in IB (Touch Up Inside) and then have this in the .m file right below @synthesize

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender { 
       NSLog(@"Button pressed"); 
       ...
}
```

Nothing is showing up in the console so for some reason the action isn't being executed. Why is this? Thanks.

Comment: How is the object (view controller?) that contains the `buttonPressed:` code being created?

Comment: Well the view controller was premade.

Comment: Are you sure that viewController is instanciated as the subclass you are expecting. e.g. `[[MyViewController alloc] init]`

Comment: @jsttn did you find answer? I have similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

The method appears fine to me. Double check that:

1. You've set in IB the class of your view controller that contains the button to the correct class.
2. When you right-click on the button in IB it has the `IBAction` hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing the rest of your code - it should look something like

```
YourViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
yourViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

make sure that you have included YourViewController.h in the .m of the calling View Controller .

Comment: I wonder if that will work. If the `NSLog` does not print anything, it's likely that the entire `IBAction` is not executed.